# Перевод букв в цифры и обратно

Tags: c++, qt

Помогите понять, в чем ошибка. Пример ниже это часть алгоритма, суть в том, что нужно найти код буквы (её порядковый номер в алфавите), изменить его и переприсвоить.
В C++ делал так:

```
//            012345678901234567890123456
string alpha{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_"};
int N=alpha.size();
string msg="hello";
string cmsg(msg.size(),'_');
for (int i=0;...;...)
cmsg.at(i)=alpha.at(alpha.find(msg.at(i)) //Сильно упрощено
```

Попытался в QT:

```
int N=alpha.size();
QString msg;
msg=ui->text_msg->text().toLower();
QString cmsg(msg.size(),'_');
cmsg.at(2)=alpha.at(alpha.indexOf(msg.at(4))); //Упрощено
```

Ошибка:

```
 ошибка: passing 'const QChar' as 'this' argument of 'QChar& QChar::operator=(const QChar&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 cmsg.at(2)=alpha.at(alpha.indexOf(msg.at(4)));
           ^
```

Comment: А чем вам Qt не C++? Почему старый код не подходит?

Comment: А по сути — судя по всему, `QString::at` выдаёт копию.

Comment: @VladD, в QT нужно прыгать через голову, чтобы string в QLineEdit засунуть и извлечь, проше использовать родной QString, но с ним at() работает коряво (о чём и вопрос). Сейчас попробовал [] вместо at() - вроде норм, но придётся много переписывать, так что не вариант (пока)

Comment: А, понимаю. Особенности платформы, в общем.

Comment: @VladD "А по сути — судя по всему, QString::at выдаёт копию" А в чём разница? Копию жевать qt отказыввается из-за объявления?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmsg.at(2)`возвращает константное значение, попробуйте вместо этого `cmsg[2]` 
Если переписывать весь код не вариант, можно оставить код на c++, а в QLineEdit поместить полученную строку можно так: `ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::fromStdString(cmsg));`

Comment: Спасибо, вроде работает, а чем ему константа не нравится?

Comment: @jumpjet67, вы ее пытаетесь изменить

Comment: cmsg.at(2) - да... кажется понял :D А в плюсах почему катит?

Comment: @jumpjet67, std::string::at возвращает ссылку, вроде как не константную

Comment: Спасибо :D. Вот небольшой под-вопрос - fromStdString это медот класса QString? Почему так странно вызывается, через :: ?

Comment: @jumpjet67 потому, что это статический метод класс QString: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

Comment: @jumpjet67 Да, это метод класса QString. Просто он статический, его можно вызывать и так, и так: QString msg; msg.fromStdString(cmsg);